# How to check the redundancy of this statement?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a file using php. The thus created file contains a lot of HTML content, along with some MySQL queries. The problem here lies on the line(3rd blue arrow), denoted by the downward facing arrow.

The main error here is due to redundancy in single inverted commas. Could anybody help me with the problem please?

Kindly see this image for code..

[image]

Comment: Please, do not post screenshots of code, it makes it very difficult to comment on sections without retyping it all. Just cut and paste it in with proper code formatting, simply indent four spaces.

Comment: Inverted commas? you mean `'` single-quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using quoted array keys within a double-quoted string. This is not permitted in PHP, though it will "politely" do the correct thing but issue a warning.

e.g.

```
$arr['foo'] = 'bar';

echo "This is wrong: $arr['foo']"; // wrong
echo "This is correct: $arr[foo]"; // right
echo "This is correct: {$arr['foo']}"; // also right
```

In all three cases, PHP will properly output 'bar' where the array reference is, the first line will cause a warning.